# Equivalent of attoparsecs `inClass` in Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec, attoparsec

I am translating some code from attoparsec to Parsec, because the parser needs to produce better error messages. The attoparsec code uses `inClass` (and `notInClass`) extensively. Is there a similar function for Parsec that lets me translate `inClass`-occurences mechanically? Hayoo and Hoogle didn't offer any insight into the matter.

```
inClass :: String -> Char -> Bool
```

`inClass "a-c'-)0-3-"` is equivalent to `\ x -> elem x "abc'()0123-"`, but the latter is inefficient and tedious to write for large ranges.

I will reimplement the function myself if nothing else is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any such combinator; if there was, it would be in [Text.Parsec.Char](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Char.html) (which is where all the standard parser combinator functions that involve `Char` are defined). You should be able to define it fairly easily.

I don't think you'll be able to get the same performance advantages attoparsec does with [its implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#inClass), though; it relies on the internal `FastSet` type, which only works with 8-bit characters. Of course, if you don't need Unicode support, that might not be a problem, but the [code for `FastSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-FastSet.html#memberChar) implies you'll get unpredictable results passing Chars greater than `'\255'`, so if you want to reuse the `FastSet`-based solution, you'll at least have to read the strings you're parsing in [binary mode](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.4.1.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#g:21). (You'll also have to copy the implementation of `FastSet` into your program, as it's not exported...)

If your range strings are short, then a simple solution like this is likely to be pretty fast:

```
type Range = (Char, Char)

inClass :: String -> Char -> Bool
inClass = inClass' . parseClass

parseClass :: String -> [Range]
parseClass "" = []
parseClass (a:'-':b:xs) = (a, b) : parseClass xs
parseClass (x:xs) = (x, x) : parseClass xs

inClass' :: [Range] -> Char -> Bool
inClass' cls c = any (\(a,b) -> c >= a && c <= b) cls
```

You could even try something like this, which *should* be at least as efficient as the above version (including when many calls to a single `inClass s` are made), and additionally avoid the list traversal overhead:

```
inClass :: String -> Char -> Bool
inClass "" = const False
inClass (a:'-':b:xs) = \c -> (c >= a && c <= b) || f c where f = inClass xs
inClass (x:xs) = \c -> c == x || f c where f = inClass xs
```

(taking care to move the recursion *out* of the lambda; I don't know if GHC can/will do this itself.)

Comment: The question wasn't really asking for a solution, and I'll probably end up writing a TH macro for this, but the above code solves the problem very well.

Comment: I figured I'd add some value as far as efficient implementation goes, since "nope, sorry" isn't very helpful for future visitors :)

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no equivalent in parsec. You have to write it yourself. I see two main options,

1. parse the `inClass` syntax to create a `String` from it, to use with `oneOf`
2. parse it to create a function to pass to `satisfy`

the former is of course a special case of the latter, and if you have longer ranges in your class, it will be less efficient. But it's probably a bit easier to implement.

```
(|||) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
p ||| q = \x -> p x || q x
(&&&) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
p &&& q = \x -> p x && q x

parseClass (l:'-':h:more) = ((>= l) &&& (<= h)) ||| parseClass more
parseClass (c:cs) = (== c) ||| parseClass cs
parseClass [] = const False
```

is a simple-minded possibility.